# dwoo separate tpl files from compiled templates cache

Tags: php, templates, dwoo

I'm using dwoo as php template engine for separate application logic from display logic. I think that it's done very well but I'm having a little "problem".

dwoo for every template generate in the same directory of the template a file with the same name of the template but with the extension .d132 (I think that 132 is the version of dwoo). This file is the compiled templates cache.

My little problem is that I can't find a way to separate template files from the compiled templates cache, I mean separate them in another directory, so that the directory of the templates is cleaner and neater.

Comment: Even though I never heard about this engine before, using Google, it took me about 15-20 seconds to find the docs and what you're looking for: http://dwoo.org/documentation/v1.3/dwoo-for-developers.html (the Set directories-part at the bottom).

Comment: I swear I didn't notice it and I'm using it since 1 month. Thank you very much.

Comment: A suggestion for future questions, you _really_ need to do some proper research and specifically read the docs properly before posting a question. SO should be the last resort if you really can't find the answer anywhere else. People tend to down vote these kinds of questions. (I didn't do that now, since I believe in giving people a heads up first and you have a good history :-) )